# React Native handle on java side addListener

Tags: android, react-native

I use addListener method of NativeEventEmitter to add listener from JavaScript to native side.

```
    import {NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter, EmitterSubscription} from 'react-native';
        const CoreBridge = NativeModules.Core;

        class Core extends NativeEventEmitter {
            constructor() {
                super(CoreBridge);
            }

            addListener(event: CoreEvent, handler: Function): EmitterSubscription {
                return super.addListener(event, handler);
            }
        }

export default new Core();
```

Can I handle addListener() on the native Java side? I have try with this but it's not called:

```
@ReactMethod
public void addListener(String event) {
//register native listener for event emitting
}
```

For iOS this can be done:

```
#pragma mark - RCTEventEmitter

- (NSArray<NSString > )supportedEvents {
    return @[EVENT_ONE,
             EVENT_TWO];
}

/// This method will be called when the first event listener is added.
- (void)startObserving {}

/// This method will be called when the last event listener is removed.
- (void)stopObserving {}
```

Can I have the same event listeners handling for Android?